# First OOP Script (PHP Email Script)

Tags: php, email

This is my first OOP script, a PHP email script designed for a site I'm working on: ndkutz(.)net. I want a user to be able to send an email to the barbershop owner from the website. I'm self taught and even though I know I'm on the right track it's not working and I feel absolutely lost. Is my code any good? Also, **I posted this on code review** to no avail.

```
<?php

 $error = '';
 $errormsg = '';
 $finalMessage = '';
 $finalName = '';
 $finalSubject = '';
 $finalTo = '';
 $finalHeader = '';
 $sendingEmail = '';
 $emailMessageS = '';
 $emailMessageF = '';

class emailConstruction 
{
    private $from = "";
    private $name = "";
    private $message = "";

    public function scrubAll($data) {
        $data = htmlspecialchars($data);
        $data = trim($data);
        $data = strip_tags($data);
        return $data;
    }

    public function setfrom($from){
        $this->from = stripslashes($from);
        $this->from = $from;
    }

    public function getFrom(){
        return $this->from;
    }

    public function setName($name){
        $this->name = scrubAll($name);
        $this->name = $name;
    }

    public function getName(){
        return $this->name;
    }


    public function setMessage($message){
        $this->message = scrubAll($data);
        $this->message = wordwrap($data,70,"<br />");
        $this->message = $message;
    }

    public function getMessage(){
        return $this->message;
    }
}

if(isset($_POST['submit']))
    {
        if(empty($_POST['uname']))
        {
            $error = 1;
            $errormsg = "Your name is required.";
            return false;
        }else{
            $error = 0;
            $createEmail = new emailConstruction;
            $createEmail->setName($_POST['uname']);
        }
        if(empty($_POST['umail']))
        {
            $error = 1;
            $errormsg = "Email address required.";
            return false;
        }else {
            $error = 0;
            $createEmail =  new emailConstruction;
            $createEmail->setTo($_POST['umail']);
        }
        if(empty($_POST['umsg']))
        {
            $error = 1;
            $errormsg = "Message is required";
            return false;
        }else{
            $error = 0;
            $createEmail = new emailConstruction;
            $createEmail->setMessage($_POST['umsg']);
        }
        if($error = 0)
        {   $finalHeader = 'from:' . $finalFrom;
            $finalHeader .='MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n';
            $finalHeader .='Content-type: text/html\r\n';
            $finalMessage = $createEmail->getMessage();
            $finalName = $createEmail->getName();
            $finalSubject = 'New potiential client by the name of ' . $finalName;
            $finalTo = 'madebyknight@icloud.com';

            $sendingEmail = mail($finalTo,$finalSubject,$finalMessage,$finalHeader);
            if($sendingEmail == true)
            {
                $emailMessageS = 'Email sent successfully!';
            }else{
                $emailMessageF = 'Error. Please try again!';
            }
        }
    }
?>
```

Comment: `scrubAll($var)` has to be `$this->scrubAll($var)` - unless you have an existing function outside your class of the same name.

Comment: Outside the class, `$error = 0;` will make sending email fail. Remove all lines containing it.

Comment: `if($error = 0)` <- that - to `if($error == 0)` , you're using `=` assignment operator when it should be `==` comparison.

Comment: Thank you vm! In regards to your first answer do you mean something like $this->name = $this->scrubAll($name);

Comment: Yes that's it..

Comment: Thank you so so much! Truly appreciate this.

Comment: Inside the `setName($) { }` function remove - `$this->name = $name;`

Comment: Inside the `setMessage($) { }` function remove - `$this->message = $message;`

Comment: `setMessage($message){` <- make it - `setMessage($data){` - you're using the wrong variable inside the function.

Comment: Header line not in the correct format change - `$finalHeader = 'from:' . $finalFrom;` - to - `$finalHeader = 'From: ' . $finalFrom."\r\n";`

Comment: At the topmost of your code - change - `$error = '';` to `$error = 0;`

Comment: @DottieKnight: Why reinventing the wheel? Just use an existing library like PHPMailer. You can also take a look at PHPMailers classes in their Github repository to learn more about OOP. Cheers! :)

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is a **code review request**.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, firstly, your class is currently overriding some values when you do `setXXX`. It should look like this:

```php
class emailConstruction 
{
    private $from = "";
    private $name = "";
    private $message = "";

    public function scrubAll($data) {
        $data = htmlspecialchars($data);
        $data = trim($data);
        $data = strip_tags($data);
        return $data;
    }

    public function setfrom($from){
        $this->from = stripslashes($from);
    }

    public function getFrom(){
        return $this->from;
    }

    public function setName($name){
        $this->name = scrubAll($name);
    }

    public function getName(){
        return $this->name;
    }

    public function setMessage($message){
        $this->message = wordwrap(scrubAll($data), 70, "<br />");
    }

    public function getMessage(){
        return $this->message;
    }
}
```

Notice I've removed some lines of code. Also notice how we assigned the returned value of `scrubAll($data)` to `wordwrap` inside the `setMessage()` function.

Okay, now with that fixed, let's move on!

You were trying to do some input validation at the end in your `if` statements. But you were creating a new `emailConstruction` object each time you did a check.

I've cleaned it up a little:

```php
if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
  $error = 0;

  if (empty($_POST['uname'])) {
    $error = 1;
    $errormsg = "Your name is required.";
  }

  if (empty($_POST['umail'])) {
    $error = 1;
    $errormsg = "Email address required.";
  }

  if (empty($_POST['umsg'])) {
    $error = 1;
    $errormsg = "Message is required";
  }

  if ($error === 0) {
    $createEmail = new emailConstruction();
    $createEmail->setName($_POST['uname']);
    $createEmail->setTo($_POST['umail']);
    $createEmail->setMessage($_POST['umsg']);

    $finalHeader = 'from:' . $finalFrom;
    $finalHeader .='MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n';
    $finalHeader .='Content-type: text/html\r\n';
    $finalMessage = $createEmail->getMessage();
    $finalName = $createEmail->getName();
    $finalSubject = 'New potiential client by the name of ' . $finalName;
    $finalTo = 'madebyknight@icloud.com';

    $sendingEmail = mail($finalTo, $finalSubject, $finalMessage, $finalHeader);

    if ($sendingEmail == true) {
        $emailMessageS = 'Email sent successfully!';
    } else {
        $emailMessageF = 'Error. Please try again!';
    }
  } else {
    // Some fields were not filled up.
    // Do something.
  }
}
```

And although it doesn't affect the functionality of your code, there are also some conventions that would be good to adopt.

- Class names usually begin with a capital letter. So instead of naming your class `emailConstruction`, you'd name it `EmailConstruction`.
- It's also a good practice to try to name classes using nouns instead of verbs where possible. For instead of naming the class `EmailConstruction`, we'd call it `EmailMessage`, or something like that.

There are a lot more nitty-gritty conventions that people use, but you'll cross that bridge when you get to it!

Comment: **Thank you!** I only feel foolish, not absolutely foolish. Lol.